# UILabel resize height not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the following code to resize height of the label but it isn't working.
It is showing the text with .....
What did i do wrong?

```
float storeAddress1YOffset=10;
float storeAddress1XWidth=scrollView.frame.size.width;
float storeAddressLabel1YHeight=15;
UILabel *storeAddressLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(Xoffset,storeSectionHeight+ storeAddress1YOffset,storeAddress1XWidth, storeAddressLabel1YHeight) ];
storeAddressLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:15.0f];
currentHeight=currentHeight + storeAddress1YOffset + storeAddressLabel1YHeight;
[storeAddressLabel setText:fullAddress];

CGRect labelFrame = storeAddressLabel.frame;
labelFrame.size = [fullAddress sizeWithFont:storeAddressLabel.font
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(storeAddressLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                lineBreakMode:storeAddressLabel.lineBreakMode];
storeAddressLabel.frame = labelFrame;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work for me. There are a few variables you didn't instantiate:

```
float Xoffset = ?;
float storeSectionHeight = ?;
float currentHeight = ?;
NSString *fullAddress = @"?";
```

As well as you don't show any details about `scrollView` or adding `storeAddressLabel` to (I'm assuming) `scrollView` as a subview.

When I filled in these missing pieces, using a plain `UIView`, the label appeared resized correctly to a test string `fullAddress`. Please include some more of your code, including these missing pieces.

Comment: I got it working by determine the frame size before initializing the frame label.